# Hide the iPhone status bar in a web application?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

Is there a way to disable the status bar in iPhone web apps? I'm working on something that requires a fixed, fullscreen view, and the status bar is rather annoying.

Comment: Are you talking about the bar on top?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in a web app.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not possible.

Comment: However please go to http://bugreport.apple.com and file a request for this enhancement, adding enough weight to this will eventually result in Apple implementing it.

Comment: It is not a bag - it is a feature.

Comment: It's definitely not a bag.

Comment: A workaround suggestion : Use translucent mode, set page background to white and add some margin from top. :)

Comment: It is possible. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunatly, no. There are only two options `black` and `black-translucent`. Just note that with `black-translucent` part of the web frame will be partially visible under the status bar while using `black` actually pushes the web frame down so it's height is a little smaller.

This is what Apple says in their [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

> This meta tag has no effect unless you first specify full-screen mode as described in [“apple-mobile-web-app-capable.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW3)
>
> If `content` is set to `default`, the status bar appears normal. If set to `black`, the status bar has a black background. If set to `black-translucent`, the status bar is black and translucent. If set to `default` or `black`, the web content is displayed below the status bar. If set to `black-translucent`, the web content is displayed on the entire screen, partially obscured by the status bar. The default value is `default`.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen that you might have to remove the web application from your home screen, and then add it again, if you've added the meta tag, for it to make any difference. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is, at least by now, possible.
You need to add a `manifest.json` to your index.html:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

In projects like Angular, React or Vue don't forget to include this file in the assets otherwise your browser will not know about this file.

You can build your manifest.json like this

```
{
   "name": "Your App-name",
   "short_name": "short",
   "display": "standalone",
   "orientation": "landscape",
   "start_url": "http://linkToYourSite:4200",
   "scope": "http://linkToYourSite:4200",
   "icons": [{
        "src": "assets/images/logo.png",
        "sizes": "64x64",
        "type": "image/png"
    }]
}
```

It is essential that the start_url and the scope are identical or the start_url is at least within the scope. If you then save your app as a Progressive Web App on your device, all pages within the scope will be displayed without a status bar.

Comment: is this working for anoyne? not for me. I'm trying it on local dev, with a react.js app.

Comment: @samplecode3300 this is quite a while since then but did you put the manifest.json into reacts `/public` folder? Maybe also try to clear the browsers cache and hard reload the page. It should work locally too as I also used my local IP.
Also checkout if you can access the manifest.json in the root of your website.

Comment: Thanks for checking in on this! So I what I was asking for "hiding the status bar" was in context of a safari browser, and NOT, downloading / saving the app as a progressive web app (which via Safari, is just save to home screen) 

So yes, I managed to hide the bar when the app is saved to home screen! 
I suppose its just not possible to hide the bar when in a browser.

Comment: No worries! I see your problem. This just works for PWAs, yes. Not sure if there is a solution for an actual safari tab. I can imagine that safari is not allowing that.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could get (iOS7, I think iOS6 would show darkened status bar) shows the status bar but with a transparent background and does not push down the content of the page; so you would see the network connection time and battery percent and time at the top of your app.

```
meta tags:
name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"
name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"
```

Also, to view any changes requires you to delete the app from your homescreen then add it back again.

As mentioned by andyg303:

> minimal-ui might have worked on beta, but tested and doesn't work on iPhone (iOS 7.1.2 4s) or iPad (v2 7.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">` may be a partial solution:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylhxt.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgGJV.png

You can see that the text on status bar can be hidden in the white background, but when you're scrolling, the text will still be there.

Answer (score -1):

It was added in iOS 7.1

Simply add minimal-ui to the viewport meta tag, e.g:

Taken from here:
https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2194915

Please note this only works for iPhone as far as I am aware, not iPad

Answer (score -10):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: "If content is set to yes, the web application runs in full-screen mode; otherwise, it does not. The default behavior is to use Safari to display web content. You can determine whether a webpage is displayed in full-screen mode using the window.navigator.standalone read-only Boolean JavaScript property. http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safarihtmlref/articles/metatags.html

Comment: This definition of "fullscreen" does not hide the status bar. window.navigator.standalone = true, and the status bar persists.