# How do I hide the status bar completely in an iOS 7 web app?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, web-applications

I'm building a single page JavaScript/PHP web app that currently hides the **url bar** and stays in full screen **successfully** with the following code:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

**What I need to do now** is hide the actual status bar. I've tried the following meta tags to no avail:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Is there some other meta tag or JavaScript/PHP code I could use to hide the status bar completely? I noticed that the Belly Card iPad mini web app (www.bellycard.com) does this successfully and I'm not sure how. Any insight is genuinely appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Can't do it anymore. Post on it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813476/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-address-bar-in-ios-7-safari

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct method for this ([see: similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2893951/2857130)) but... this link seems promising:

- [Everything Hybrid Web Apps Need to Know About the Status Bar in iOS7](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2013/11/07/everything-hybrid-web-apps-need-to-know-about-the-status-bar-in-ios7)

---

### The summary of the link is as below:

Key Comments (*at link*):

> When viewing sites in Safari you do not have the ability to customize
>   the status bar in any way. Previous versions of iOS offered the
>   ability to view sites in full screen mode, but that was removed in
>   iOS7, see
>   http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review.

---

Key Notes (*in link*):

> **StatusBar Cordova Plugin**
>
> With iOS7 Apple introduced some native Objective C APIs to control the
>   status bar. Because of Cordova, we have the ability to bridge these
>   native APIs directly into JavaScript APIs.
>   Luckily for us @shazron has already done this with the [StatusBar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/plugins/statusbar).
>
> After adding the plugin to your application, you are given a StatusBar
>   object with a number of methods to manipulate the status bar in
>   JavaScript directly.
>   ...
>   You can hide the status bar using **StatusBar.hide()**, or even change its
>   background color with StatusBar.backgroundColorByName() or
>   StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString().
>   For example, the following sets the status bar to green.
>
> ```
> <script>      
>     document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
>         StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
>         StatusBar.backgroundColorByName('green');
>     }, false);
> </script>
> ```
>
> ...
>   **Outstanding Issues**
>
> While the web has come up with workarounds for most of the iOS7 status
>   bar issues, there are still a few that remain unresolved.
>
> - The status bar still overlays content displayed in a cordova [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser).
>     There is no known workaround, but a fix is [slated for cordova 3.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4930).
> - The StatusBar plugin does not work in apps that lock the device into landscape mode.

---

Key Critic Comment (*at link*):

> These solutions seem to be working only for Phonegap applications, for
>   us who don't use this and simply wrap our apps in a webview it seems
>   the only easy solution is to set the webview's top property to 20
>   instead of zero and that takes care of the issue at hand.